# Word Pyramids Up and Down

Tags: word, word-square

Using the letters complete the puzzle so that

A seven letter word

A five letter word

A four letter word

3x 3 letter words are created

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

How about

> [image]

Where the words are

> 7 letters: ENGAGED
> 5 letters: DIGIT
> 4 letters: SAGA
> 3 letters: [FAD](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fad), FIG and DIG
>
> And all the letters required are used.

Comment: Is 'fad' not a common word where you are from? I am surprised.

Comment: @LannyStrack can't say I've ever heard it before :)